# How to find the last non null value of a column and recursively find the sum value of another column

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a column A and currently fetched value of A is null. I need to go back to previous rows and find the non -null value of column A. Then I need to find the sum of another column B from the point non value is seen till the current point. After that I need to add the sum of B with A, which will be new value of A.

For finding the column A non null value I have written the query as

```
nvl(last_value(nullif(A,0)) ignore nulls over (order by A),0)
```

But I need to do the calculation of B as mentioned above.

```
nvl(last_value(nullif(A,0)) ignore nulls over (order by A),0)
```

Can anyone please help me out ?

Sample data

```
A        B      date

null     20     14/06/2019

null     40     13/06/2019

10       50     12/06/2019
```

here value of A on 14/06/2019 should be replaced by sum of B + value of A on 12/06/2019(which is the 1st non null value of A)=20+40+50+10=120

Comment: Sample data would help.

Comment: if today A' value is null and there is a value for A 2 days ago. Suppose it is 10000 . Suppose B is 20000 yesterday ,10000 2 days ago and 30000 today.  sum of B is 50000.Then new value of A is sum of B + A's value,which is 50000+10000=60000

Comment: I need to find a way to find sum of B.

Comment: What do you mean by "today" and "two days ago"? Is there a column of `date` data type or similar? Your code doesn't reflect that; your ordering is by the values in column `A` itself (which doesn't really make much sense regardless), not by another "date" column, which would make a lot more sense.

Comment: Yes there is a column of date datatype available,but the problem is not with the date.As I mentioned I need to find that point where the non value of A is seen and from that point I need to calculate sum of B.

Comment: @Jill you'd better to edit the question with sample data and expected results depending on those data rather than commenting.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I have edited the question with sample data

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is handled by using

`sum(<column>) over (...)` together with `last_value over (...)` function as below 
 :

```
with t( A,B, "date" ) as
(
 select null, 20, date'2019-06-14' from dual union all
 select null, 40, date'2019-06-13' from dual union all
 select 10   ,50, date'2019-06-12' from dual
)
select nvl(a,sum(b) over (order by 1)+
             last_value(a) ignore nulls
                    over (order by 1 desc)
          ) as a,
       b, "date" 
  from t; 

A   B   date
--- --  ----------
120 20  14.06.2019
120 40  13.06.2019
 10 50  12.06.2019
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/YGGNX2366)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you have version 12c or higher:

```
with t( A,B, dte ) as
(
 select null, 20, date'2019-06-14' from dual union all
 select null, 40, date'2019-06-13' from dual union all
 select 10   ,50, date'2019-06-12' from dual
)
select * from t
match_recognize(
  order by dte desc
  measures
    nvl(
      first(a),
      y.a + sum(b)
    ) as a,
    first(b) as b,
    first(dte) as dte
  after match skip to next row
  pattern(x* y{0,1})
  define x as a is null,
    y as a is not null
);

     A          B DTE       
------ ---------- ----------
   120         20 2019-14-06
   100         40 2019-13-06
    10         50 2019-12-06
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional count to divide data into separate groups, then use this group for analytical calculation:

```
select a, b, dt, grp, sum(nvl(a, 0) + nvl(b, 0)) over (partition by grp order by dt) val
  from (
    select a, b, dt, count(case when a is not null then 1 end) over (order by dt) grp
      from t order by dt desc)
  order by dt desc
```

Sample result:

```
     A          B DT                 GRP        VAL
------ ---------- ----------- ---------- ----------
               20 2019-06-14           4        120
               40 2019-06-13           4        100
    10         50 2019-06-12           4         60
     5          2 2019-06-11           3          7
     6          1 2019-06-10           2          7
                3 2019-06-09           1         14
     7          4 2019-06-08           1         11
```

**<sup>[demo](https://rextester.com/MVPIS94909)</sup>**